Calculate number of months between two dates by Excel formula
I need calculate number of months between two dates in Excel.
If the day of the starting date is less than 2 then this month is counted as 1.
If the day of the starting date more or equal 2, then this month does not count.

Starting date is any date specified by user. Ending date is always 31.12.2023.
If starting date 01.05.2023 then number of month as 8 (because 01 of May less than 2)
If starting date 02.08.2023 then number of month as 4 (because 02 of August greater (or equal) 2).
Formula:
=IF(DAY(A1)<2;  (IF(DAY("31.12.2023") >= DAY(A1); (YEAR("31.12.2023") - YEAR(A1)) * 12 + MONTH("31.12.2023") - MONTH(A1) + 1; (YEAR("31.12.2023") - YEAR(A1)) * 12 + MONTH("31.12.2023") - MONTH(A1))); IF(DAY("31.12.2023") >= DAY(A1); (YEAR("31.12.2023") - YEAR(A1)) * 12 + MONTH("31.12.2023") - MONTH(A1) + 1; (YEAR("31.12.2023") - YEAR(A1)) * 12 + MONTH("31.12.2023") - MONTH(A1))-1)

It works, but this quite huge formula. Is it possible to simplify or use more effective way? (I can't use DateDif because our Office versions does not support this function. I can't use VBA macroses.

=(2023-YEAR(A1-1))*12 + 12-MONTH(A1-1)

I doubt DATEDIF is not supported by your Excel version. It works from Excel 2013 and up, however the formula helper will not appear. You need to type the formula manually.

Thanks. Yes there was no hint and I thought that it is not supported.

@ScottCraner - what's the situation if a comment is the correct soln (should it ever get posted as the soln or left in comment format)? Yours is correct - and I can't think of any improvement given parsimony... post it mate.

@JB-007 if I comment it usually means I do not have the time for a formal answer and have no problem if someone wants to make it into a formal answer.  By formal answer I mean explaining what the formula does and other information as needed.

@ScottCraner cool - but I guess I'm trying to ascertain is: what is supposed to be the convention in such cases?i.e Others can't replicate your soln in the answer block that's just lame - so is it fine just to leave the answer in the comment section (thus keeping the Q 'unanswered' in filters etc. and not letting other users easily determine what the best soln is if they have a similar query?  It just seems to me that if you typed exactly what you typed in the comment section, but in the answer block - it would suffice mate.  Pls don't take me wrong way - I'm not criticizing, just commenting

@ScottCraner - please see "When shouldn't I comment?" in guidance for 'adding comments' - please refrain from posting solutions like this in the comment box from now on (would be great if you could remove previous ones you are aware of)...
https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

It turned out that DateDif is supported by most Excel versions. Just hint not displayed.
With the help of DateDif:
=IF(DAY(A1)<2; DATEDIF(A1; $E$1; "m")+1; DATEDIF(A1; $E$1; "m"))

Where $E$1 is set up to "31.12.2023" or any other date.
